# Entering into forms using urllib2

Tags: python, post, selenium, urllib2, urllib

im writing a program to download music and im trying to completly change it into urllib2 but i cant seem to get the part where is enter the url information into the download site

Here is my code:

```
import urllib2, urllib, urllister
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

raw_i=raw_input("Search: ")
x = urllib.quote_plus(raw_i)

site1 = urllib2.urlopen('Youtube Serch URL')
y = site1.read()
parser = urllister.URLLister()
parser.feed(y)

parser.close()


for url in parser.urls:
   if "watch?v=" in url: 
        v = url

        break


vid = ("Video URL")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("Youtube to Mp3 Site URL")


elem = driver.find_element_by_id("youtube-url")
elem.clear()                                      #This Bit I want in urllib
elem.send_keys(vid)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)
download = driver.page_source

parser = urllister.URLLister()
parser.feed(download)
parser.close
driver.quit()

for url in parser.urls:
    if "/get?video_id" in url: 
        down = url

download_url = ("Download URL")

filename, headers = urllib.urlretrieve(download_url, 'Download.mp3')
```

it all works fine but i cant seem to get the selenium part to be urllib 
i just need to clear the submit form then input the video url then push enter or click the convert button

Please Help!!

Comment: You really should use curl for this type of operations.

Comment: When you submit the form there will be done a post or something. look into to `<form action=...>` tag. you can use that I think.